# Is it bad style to inject IConfigurationRoot into a class of the business logic- or data access-layer?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

We have an ASP.NET Core 1.1 application which is splitted in 3 layers:

- Web
- Business Logic (BLL)
- Data Access (DAL)

There we have some methods of the BLL and some of the DAL that need some values from the config. I see two possibilities to pass them the required values:

- define the values as parameters of the method, get them in the web-layer and pass them to the BLL and DAL
- inject IConfigurationRoot to the BLL and DAL

Which of the both possibilities is more recommendable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With ASP.NET Core you should actually choose the third possibility:

- use strongly typed settings injected with `IOptions<T>` wrapper.

Here is a sample:

**POCO for the settings:**

```
public class SomeSettings
{
    public string SomeStringValue { get; set; }

    public int SomeNumericValue { get; set; }

    // ... 
}
```

**Injecting the settings:**

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly SomeSettings settings;

    public SomeClass(IOptions<SomeSettings> options)
    {
        this.settings = options.Value;
    }
}
```

**Registering the settings:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //  ...

    services.Configure<SomeSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SectionNameHere"));
}
```

Using Options pattern is [recommended way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options) to deal with configuration in .NET Core.